# Which is better, brass or plastic fittings for pex-a pipe (which uses expansion fittings)?

Tags: pex

We are replumbing an old house with pex-a in a north central Texas.  I have seen pros and cons for using brass vs plastic fittings.  There does not seem to be a consensus on the best choice.  Price is not the deciding factor; we want the best solution.  What are the experiences or recommendations you can provide to help make a decision?  Pex-a will run all the way from the meter (45 feet from street to house) and then everywhere in the house.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the foundation--slab on grade or pier and beam with crawlspace?

Comment: Where in North Texas? Is this an area with mice or rats? Are others repiping in PEX? Whic manufacturer of PEX-A are you considering? See https://youtu.be/tJI-E6y2DuU

Comment: This is pier and beam with crawl space.  We would use whatever brand is available at Home Depot.